# Using a function on stylesheet typescript react native

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-stylesheet

I try to use some `variables` inside my `StyleSheet` file.

The UI is working fine. But the type is error.

Any idea how to solve this?

```
type buttonStyle = (height: number, width: string, color: string) => ViewStyle;

export type Styles = {
  button: buttonStyle;
};
```

```
export default StyleSheet.create<Styles>({
  button: (height: number, width: string, color: string) => ({
    height: height,
    width: width,
    backgroundColor: color,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderRadius: 10,
  }),
});
```

This is the error message from type.

```
Type 'Styles' does not satisfy the constraint 'NamedStyles<any> | NamedStyles<Styles>'.
  Type 'Styles' is not assignable to type 'NamedStyles<Styles>'.
    Types of property 'button' are incompatible.
      Type 'buttonStyle' is not assignable to type 'ViewStyle | TextStyle | ImageStyle
```

Comment: Did you already define the stylesheet before?.

Comment: Did you already try this? https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/29651

Comment: very good question but sadly there is no proper answer

Answer (score -1):

You can create a const style using StyleSheet.create() outside of your component:

```
const styles = ((height: number, width: string, color: string)) => StyleSheet.create({
    btn: {
        height: height,
        width: width,
        backgroundColor: color,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        borderRadius: 10,
    }
});
```

and than call it like this in your component:

```
<Button style={styles(height: height, width: width, color: color).btn} />
```

Comment: @Imasneri They probably downvoted because the question asked how to fix the types so that a function in the StyleSheet doesn't give a compiler error, and you gave a workaround as opposed to answering the question.

Comment: it is not how it works ? If something does not work we find a workaround so that it works ? It is just called a solution ?

Comment: No, a workaround and a solution are different. That doesn't mean you can't provide a workaround instead, but for a workaround to be a good answer you'd want to explain why the solution the poster was looking for doesn't exist (not sure this is even the case), then explain why the tradeoffs of using your workaround and why it is workable.

Not to mention that the workaround you give of creating an entire new stylesheet every time any argument changes is not a viable solution for many use cases, since this will be quite inefficient.

Comment: Okey thank you for taking time to explain!

Answer (score -2):

```
export default StyleSheet.create<Styles | any>({
  button: (height: number, width: string, color: string) => ({
    height: height,
    width: width,
    backgroundColor: color,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderRadius: 10,
  }),
});
```

add type [any](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) like `this`,

```
StyleSheet.create<Styles | any>
```

Comment: any is not a solution

Answer (score -5):

I think StyleSheet does not contain function type. So I fix this error with this approach.

style file

```
import type { ViewStyle } from 'react-native';

const styles = {
  button: (height: number, width: string, color: string): ViewStyle => ({
    height: height,
    width: width,
    backgroundColor: color,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderRadius: 10,
  }),
};

export default styles;
```

No need to define the styles type.